# Line break in woocommerce email

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

So im trying to customize my woocommerce mail. I've moved them from the plugin folder to the theme-child folder.

I've tried using:



\n and \r\n (with and without nl2br after echo)

It just won't break my line, and my hair starts to get gray now.

My Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php _e ( "Kære Kastaniestrik kunde,\n
Vi har nu gennemført ordren og din pakke er på vej til dig og udleveres hos den valgte pakkeshop.\n
Har du yderligere spørgsmål til din ordre er du velkommen til at skrive til os via kontaktformularen på vores hjemmeside under menupunktet ”kontakt”. Angiv dit ordrenummer og spørgsmål i beskeden, så sørger vi for at hjælpe dig.\n
Vi håber at du bliver glad for dit køb. Rigtig god fornøjelse og god strikkelyst.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

https://pastebin.com/gNJ1hVrN

Comment: Have you tried `<br />`

Comment: Textmail: use `\n`, HTMLmail: use `<br>`

Comment: care to share some code? It will be easy to help you rather than us just guessing out here :)

Comment: I've already tried all above without luck. code: https://pastebin.com/gNJ1hVrN

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same question. I found adding a separate php code section between < p >  tags worked. I'm only editing the last line break desired. Try this:

```
<p><?php _e ( "Kære Kastaniestrik kunde,\n
Vi har nu gennemført ordren og din pakke er på vej til dig og udleveres hos den valgte 
pakkeshop.\n Har du yderligere spørgsmål til din ordre er du velkommen til at skrive til os via
kontaktformularen på vores hjemmeside under menupunktet ”kontakt”. Angiv dit ordrenummer 
og spørgsmål i beskeden, så sørger vi for at hjælpe dig.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<p>
<?php esc_html_e( 'Vi håber at du bliver glad for dit køb. Rigtig god 
fornøjelse og god strikkelyst.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</p>

<?php
```